# Enviar ID, hacer una consulta y reflejar datos en modal bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, pdo, modal

Estoy diseñando un dashboard y creé una tabla donde trae datos de diferentes personas. Estoy tratando de hacer que la tabla se lleve el "NUMDOC" de cada persona a través de un botón, para que con ese "NUMDOC" traiga datos de otra tabla.
El problema, es que a la hora de hacer clic en el botón, únicamente me aparece el "backdrop" del modal de Bootstrap.

[image: Imagen a modo de ilustración. El ojo representaría el botón que está puesto actualmente en el código.]
*Imagen a modo de ilustración. El ojo representaría el botón que está puesto actualmente en el código. La idea es que se entienda un poco mejor cómo aparece en la tabla. Reflejará solo 5 resultados ya que tiene un LIMIT en la consulta $sql.*

Primeramente, voy a compartir el código de mi tabla con su consulta php:

**Consulta PHP**

```
<?php   
        require_once 'controllers/connection.php';
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
              
          define("ROW_PER_PAGE",2);

            $search_keyword = '';
              if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
                $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
              }
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM padronint WHERE nombre LIKE :keyword OR numdoc LIKE :keyword OR domicilio LIKE :keyword OR telefono LIKE :keyword LIMIT 5;';
        
            /* Pagination Code starts */
            $per_page_html = '';
            $page = 1;
            $start=0;
              if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
                $page = $_POST["page"];
                $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
              }
            $limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
            $pagination_statement = $connect->prepare($sql);
            $pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pagination_statement->execute();
        
            $row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
              if(!empty($row_count)){
                $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
                $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
                if($page_count>1) {
                    for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
                        if($i==$page){ //<li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">1</a></li>
                            $per_page_html .= '<li class="page-item"><input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="page-link" /></li>';
                        } else {
                            $per_page_html .= '<li class="page-item"><input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="page-link" /></li>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                $per_page_html .= "</div>";
              }
        
            $query = $sql.$limit;
            $pdo_statement = $connect->prepare($query);
            $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pdo_statement->execute();
            $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      ?>
```

**Tabla HTML QUE MUESTRA LOS RESULTADOS DE DICHA CONSULTA**

```
      <form name="frmSearch" class="" action="" method="post">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Tabla <b>Internados</b></h2></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="search-box">
                            <input type="text" name="search[keyword]" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar&hellip;" value="<?php echo $search_keyword; ?>" id='keyword' maxlength='25'>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- GUARDADO DE DATOS -->

            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>DNI<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                        <th>Domicilio</th>
                        <th>Telefono</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php if (empty($result) === false): ?>
                    <?php foreach($result as $row): ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['nombre']) ?></td>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['numdoc']) ?></td>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['domicilio']) ?></td>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['telefono']) ?></td>
                        <td><?= '<button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#getuser" data-id="<?php echo $row["numdoc"]?>" id="getUser" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Ver</button>'; ?>
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-eye">
                          <!--<a href="#" class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                          <a href="#" class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>-->
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script>
                        $('#getuser').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                          var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
                          var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
                          var modal = $(this);
                          var dataString = 'id=' + recipient;

                          $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "controllers/modalc.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                modal.find('.dash').html(data);
                            },
                            error: function(err) {
                                console.log(err);
                           }
                       });
                       })              
            </script>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <!-- <div class="hint-text">Showing <b>5</b> out of <b>25</b> entries</div> -->
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link"><i class="fa-solid fa-left-from-line"></i></a></li>
                    <?php echo $per_page_html; ?>
                    <!--
                    <li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">1</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">2</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">3</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">4</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link">5</a></li>-->
                    <li class="page-item"><a href="#" class="page-link"><i class="fa-solid fa-right-from-line"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
  </form>
```

**SCRIPT QUE ALMACENA EL "NUMDOC" DE CADA PERSONA QUE APARECE EN LA TABLA**

```
                <script>
                        $('#getuser').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                          var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
                          var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
                          var modal = $(this);
                          var dataString = 'id=' + recipient;

                          $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "controllers/modalc.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                modal.find('.dash').html(data);
                            },
                            error: function(err) {
                                console.log(err);
                           }
                       });
                       })              
            </script>
```

Como se ve en el script, técnicamente solicita un archivo dentro de la carpeta "controllers", llamado "modalc.php". Este archivo es usar el ID que guarda el AJAX y simplemente hacer la consulta para que distribuya los datos en el modal, comparto el código a continuación:

**CÓDIGO PHP DEL ARCHIVO MODALC.PHP**

```
    <?php 

include('connection.php');

if(isset($_GET["numdoc"]))
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM internacion, padronint WHERE historia = '".$_GET["numdoc"]."'";

 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $output = '<div class="row">';
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '
  <div class="col-md-9">
   <br />
   <p><label>Nombre :&nbsp;</label>'.$row["nombre"].'</p>
   <p><label>Nro Int. :&nbsp;</label>'.$row["nro_internacion"].'</p>
   <p><label>Telcod :&nbsp;</label>'.$row["telcod"].'</p>
   <p><label>Nomgar :&nbsp;</label>'.$row["nomgar"].'</p>
   <p><label>Usuario :&nbsp;</label>'.$row["usuario"].' years</p>
  </div>
  </div><br />
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}

?>
```

**CÓDIGO DEL MODAL UTILIZADO EN ESTE SISTEMA (BOOTSTRAP)**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="getuser" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

En este sistema estoy utilizando: Bootstrap, jQuery, Ajax, MySQL, PHP (PDO).

Comment: y como abres el modal?

Comment: y como consultas los datos que quieres traer en el modal ???

Comment: como escribes los datos en el modal???

Comment: la explicacion que agregas no explica lo que hace tu codigo....

Comment: Lo que hace el código es traer los datos en una tabla, de ahí automáticamente al darle clic al botón se guarda el NUMDOC para utilizarlo en otra consulta MySQL PDO y compara con otros datos de otra tabla.
 Es algo parecido a un CRUD, no se si me explico.

Comment: Hace más de un mes que trato de entender cómo hacerlo pero no me sale :/

Comment: ha ok entonces estas intentando guardar en un campo en la tabla un numero de referencia para despues usarlo para consultas en otra tabla.... como que esta muy elavorado para algo que se pudo resolver mediante otras tecnicas de diseño....

Comment: pero sigo sin entender cual es el problema.... no guarda el numdoc o no hace la segunda consulta??? de todo el código que agregaste , en parte es inútil por que no sirve para reproducir el error... no agregaste la estructura de tu base de datos.... y no veo que hayas comprobado que datos recibe por `GET` `MODALC.PHP`

Comment: Es que justamente me encuentro sumamente desorientado. La idea es que ustedes puedan ver lo que hice y darle una mejor perspectiva para que yo pueda encararlo.
 La estructura de la base de datos no es mía, es de una persona tercerizada. Esto quiere decir que no depende de mí. No puedo revelar mucha información sobre ella, sí la conozco.
 MODALC.PHP debería traer datos que yo apunte en la consulta, ejemplo: nro_internacion, nombre, telcod, otras. Son tablas dentro de la base de datos.

Comment: eso no responde la pregunta que te hice:  y no veo que hayas comprobado que datos recibe por GET MODALC.PHP

Comment: Como se ve arriba, la primera consulta limitada a 5 filas, cada una tiene un botón que tiene un id="<?php echo $row["numdoc"]?>". Ese numdoc sería como un "ID" que sirve para consultar en otra tabla llamada "internacion".
 Como se ve en el código, es importante que el botón guarde ese ID ya que se usaría un script que guardaría ese ID (numdoc) y con un get traería el archivo "MODALC.PHP" que haría la otra consulta o "subconsulta" con los datos referentes a ese usuario gracias a que en todo este procedimiento se almacenó el ID (numdoc) de la persona.

Comment: no estas respondiendo mi pregunta cuando puedas responderla entonces hablamos, bye

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema en cuestión? Recibe o no los datos, los recibe y el problema es el modal? Creo que estás preguntando varias cosas.

Comment: Hola Jheyman. El problema es que no me funciona. Parte del código es a modo referencia ya que estoy interesado en un diseño más sencillo. Según Francisco, es mucho código para algo tan simple.
 La primera consulta selecciona de la tabla "padronint" las columnas: "nombre, numdoc, domicilio y telefono" con un límite de 5 filas nada más. El resultado los renderiza dentro de las etiquetas <td>.
 Después, hay un botón que dice "Ver". Cuando le das clic a ese botón, se debería abrir un modal con datos de ese paciente. La cuestión es que esos datos están en otra tabla independiente a "padronint"

Comment: El botón que está actualmente en el código: ... <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#getuser" data-id="<?php echo $row["numdoc"]?>" id="getUser" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Ver</button> ..., guarda el resultado de "numdoc".
  
 Después creé un script en ajax para que traiga el archivo "modalc.php" y dentro del modal inserte los datos de la tabla "internación", según el "numdoc"

Comment: Adjuntaré un ejemplo visual para que se entienda mejor la idea: https://i.imgur.com/paCyenP.gif